# Software for drawing pictorial electrical diagrams?

Tags: diagram

It might seem naive, but I need to prepare some pictorial wiring diagrams for a mechatronic system. Could someone recommend software/platform to use?
The example picture below belongs to http://evtv.me/2010/08/speedster-pictorial-diagrams/.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I think you'd want to do that sort of thing in a general photo editing suite, like Photoshop or Gimp.

Comment: If You loom up car schematics they may look strange , but that’s how it’s done. In the 70’s we would just use a wiring table with J#,P# and add reverse diodes to all relay coils. Contactor  might need an RC power snubber and use heavy twisted pair and/or a good ground bus for EMI issues.  Remember that most DC motors and Pumps will draw 10x rated current on startup, so consider some means to limit current then by bypass relay so as not to make PSU trip from OCP

Comment: A smarter idea is use a small motorcycle battery that can supply 100A and a lead acid  charger and batteries will drop 5 volts at the CCA rating from 12V so choose wisely. Or use an EV battery voltage with peripherals to match. SMPS will burp on transient pump loads . Do a worst case step load analysis and measure DCR of all coils

Comment: Try to redraw everything linear instead of zigzag and just show a harness then have a wiring list for all pins , or use wire gauge and type colour coded on schematic lines . Keep it vertical or horizontal for easy scrolling with very few orthogonal lines. or like PC MOBO schematics just have connector block diagrams for each device and a harness diagram

Comment: I think closing this question was a mistake. Creating wiring diagrams is just as important for production as editing schematics. In fact, I found this while looking for a free tool to help me create wiring diagram similar to what auto makers publish for their cars. Specifically, something that allows drawing colored and striped wires and inserting pictures of the modules.

Comment: Furthermore, "recommendations for specific products" restriction should not include _electrical engineering tools_ IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for can be accomplished with a
[UML editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools).
Just about any of those will let you have shapes and images, and then connectors (aka wires). And custom properties that you setup.